# How to get full info of non-owing side of relationship after ORM in views in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, jpa, orm, playframework

I had two classes: Author and Book, defined relations between both, right JPA annotations. I use MVC architecture in Play Framework. 
In controller class (Application) ORM works, I have complete info about authors  (idA and nameA), but in views, field nameA looks like empty string (idA is correct).

Below I'll explain what I mean:

in Author:

```
public class Autor extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long idA;

    @Required
    public String nameA;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    public Set<Book> books;
    }
```

and in Books:

```
public class Book extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long idB
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
              name = "creates",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_b", referencedColumnName = "id_b"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id_a")
          )
    public Set<Autor> authors;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Book> find = new Finder<Long, Book>(Long.class, Book.class);

    public static List<Book> all()
    {
    return find.all();
    }
```

I tried to get book with all authors as effect of GET request. 
I've added to routes file line:

```
GET     /books/                 controllers.Application.booksShow()
```

and created methode in Application class:

```
public static Result booksShow(Long)
  {
      return  ok(views.html.booksInfo.render(Book.all()));
  }
```

snippet in views in Scala looks like this:

```
    @for(book <- Books) {
        <li> 
            @book.title
            @book.authors.size()
            @for(author <- book.authors) {
                    <li>@author.nameA</li>
                }
        </li>
    }
```

After get request in browser I get something like this:

```
Title1 2
[empty line]
[empty line]
Title2 1
[empty line]
```

but It should be:

```
Title1 2
Author1
Author2
Title2 1
Author2
```

I tried to change booksShow method for:

```
  public static Result booksShow(Long id)
  {
      List<Books> b = Books.all();
      System.out.println(b.get(0).title);
      System.out.println(b.get(0).authors.iterator().next().nameA);
      return  ok(views.html.booksInfo.render(Ksiazka.all()));
  }
```

And In my console appeared:

```
Title1
 Author1
```

But on website, Authors are still empty;

When I changed in Scala:

```
@for(author <- book.authors) {
    <li>@author.nameA</li>
}
```

for:

```
@for(author <- book.authors) {
    <li>@author.idA</li>
}
```

I get right (nonzero, nonblank) ID's.

Any idea? I'm confused, I get idA's and size of Authors collection, but nameA's is blank.

Comment: You don't have problems with Autor/Author?

Comment: Oryginally all variables/classes names were in Polish (more or less, in fact, English and Polish names coexisted in peace) , I've changed them to clarify (for other users) just before I've published my question. As editor I used TextArea and probably I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to resolve my problem (not exactly resolve, but I'm getting result I want):

Instead of use find.all(), I pass to view result of query with join:

in Book:

```
public static List<Books> allWithAuthors()
{
    return find.fetch("authors").findList();
}
```

and in Application:

```
public static Result booksShow()
{
    return  ok(views.html.booksInfo.render(Book.allWithAuthors()));
}
```

Comment: Hm. Sorry. My comment should have gone to your question, where the inconsistency is, not here to the answer. I'll move it.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options for solving this. You could set your relationships to FetchType.EAGER in order to populate all your relationships. That's the easy way. Could end up in performance problems, but will do it for the moment.

For the future, think about what information is needed when and populate the needed fields before your session gets closed by just doing a "get"on them. This will trigger lazy loading and populate the fields for later access.

Comment: Thanks, I read about fetch and changed annotation in book class for:


    `@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(
              name = "creates",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_b", referencedColumnName = "id_b"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id_a")
              )
    public Set<Autor> authors;
    }`

but still I'm getting empty strings. I'v never used JPA and ORM, I don't know where I can find solution to my problem.

Comment: To me, that sounds like a bug in the persistence framework used by play. Your solution does exactly the same, but explicitly.